# Racket, split a list in two different size lists. And randomly

Tags: racket

I would like to code a program that given a list and a percentage, splits the list in two different size lists. It should have random pick of the elements, that way the created lists are always different.
These code is able to do that:

```
(define (clamp x a b)
  (max (min x b) a))

(define (split pct xs)
  (define pos (exact-round (* (clamp pct 0.0 1.0) (length xs))))
  (split-at (shuffle xs) pos))
```

Here is an example:

(split 0.25 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

'(6 2)

'(3 7 1 4 5 8 9)

But, instead of "shuffle" I would like to use this function to achieve the same:

```
(define (get-randomly-no-pair list)
  (list-ref list (random (length list))))
```

so, get-randomly-no-pair takes one element randomly from the initial list. And all the elements are used to create both lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (shuffle-list lst)
  (define indexes (shuffle (range (length lst))))
  (lambda ()
    (begin0
      (list-ref lst (car indexes))
      (set! indexes (cdr indexes)))))

(define gen (shuffle-list (list 10 12 14 16 18 20))
(gen) ; ==> 14 (e.g.)
```

Now I see you assume you need to pass the list then I would rather make a mapper:

```
(define (shuffle-accessor len)
  (define indexes (list->vector (shuffle (range len))))
  (lambda (lst index)
    (list-ref lst (vector-ref indexes index))))

(define lst3-ref (shuffle-accessor 3))
(lst3-ref '(1 2 3) 0) ; ==> 3 (e.g.)
(lst3-ref '(6 7 8) 0) ; ==> 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sylwester but I think I didn't make myself clear, thats is why I edited the question. Hope, now it is easier to understand what I want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: @RobJr Still not very clear. Your function `split` does what you want according to your examples, why do you need to replace `shuffle`?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Because I am learning Racket (a better definition is that I am struggling with Racket), and I want to see how could be take and element from a list randomly and remove that element from the list (at least is the way I would do it)

Comment: @RobJr You're not in Kansas anymore! In `#lang racket` lists are immutable. You would need to change language to a standard Scheme or use a different data structure (`mcons`) and still you will have a problem removing the first element. You should try to make most of your code functional and then you need to avoid mutation of both bindings and objects.

Comment: Thanks!! Very useful (for me) your comments