# Racket, split a list in a given number of lists

Tags: racket

I would like to code a program that given a list and a number, splits the list in the given number of lists.

For example,

```
(split 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
```

Should make three lists (for example, because the list are done randomly):

```
‘(4 1 6)

‘(9 7 2)

‘(3 10 8 5)
```

It should have random pick of the elements, that way the created lists are always different.

Once I have the code, I will compare it with this one that I got [in another question at this web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406660/racket-split-a-list-in-two-different-size-lists-and-randomly). (I am learning Racket)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(define (n-way-split n lst)
  (define (go len* lst)
    (match len*
      ['() '()]
      [`(,len . ,len*-tail)
       (let-values ([(next-len-elems rest-of-elems) (split-at lst len)])
         (cons next-len-elems (go len*-tail rest-of-elems)))]))
  (go (n-way-split-length* n (length lst))
      (shuffle lst)))

(define (n-way-split-length* n len)
  (let*-values ([(quot rem)                     (quotient/remainder len n)]
                [(count/lists-of-length-quot)   (- n rem)]
                [(count/lists-of-length-quot+1) rem]
                [(size*) (append (make-list count/lists-of-length-quot   quot)
                                 (make-list count/lists-of-length-quot+1 (+ 1 quot)))])
    size*))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brendam! That is what I wanted exactly, it really helps me. Thank you indeed!